# VS2022 Community - Vanilla ASP/C#.Net crashes immeditely in IISExpress with Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crash

Using Visual Studio Community 2022 targeting .Net 4.7.2.  I create a new C# ASP.Net 4.7.2 web project (NO CORE)

I did not make any changes to the code, project, or solution.  I press play after the project creation and the application crashes.  The error starts out "**Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError'**" followed by '**System.ExecutionEngineException**'

I came to SO and researched this issue and I have found some decent looking posts.  My crash is different.  This is not crashing in user code.  The first line of the call stack shows the crash happened in external code.

I've tried all the hacks in Component Services to grant permissions.  I've tried modifying the registry directly but my company group policy does not allow this.

I've looked in the event viewer and found some interesting information and tried to act on it (read above)

**The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
{2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54}
and APPID
{15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402}
to the user THA\Andy2394 SID (S-1-5-21-117609710-507921405-1801674531-26297) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable).**

What is a **'Unavailable SID'?**  That doesn't seem correct to me.  I thought everything had a SID to it.  Do I need to check and fix any disk errors?

This local comserver executable is called RuntimeBroker.exe.

I can only suspect that code in RuntimeBroker.exe or code that it raises before entering my code is considered dangerous to the CLR.

This problem is driving me batty and it is preventing me from doing my job.  Aside from reimaging machine and starting over hoping it is something microsoft related and related to order of operation on installation, I need some direction please.

Comment: 1) Not a surprise if you are using a hardened machine, as either the system or your account has been ripped of certain default settings/permissions which I don't think anyone can easily restore (trials and attempts won't work out even if you can find articles from search engines). 2) As this is very environment specific, no one can help remotely over the internet. You might find someone locally to help, or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am calling this "an answer", it is not satisfying at all.  My organization uses Cylance.  Since I am an admin in our organization, I removed my machine from its list of machines to protect.  That solved the problem.

Others have mentioned Cylance so they deserve most of the credit for this answer that is not an answer.

!!!I would not recommend this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Update:  The previous answer is not complete.  Sorry.  I have been dealing with this for 2 days and didn't capture all my info.

In order to continue with my answer that I don't recommend, you need to boot into safe mode.

Then add a DWORD32 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cylance\Desktop called "SelfProtectionLevel" and set the value to 1.

Reboot

You now should be able to stop the Cylance service and uninstall it and find a better A/V that works for engineers.

Sorry that this whole adventure put a sour taste in my mouth and a rankerous oder in my nose.

I guess I understand that software development by nature would be considered dangerous to AV software.  Where's a video of McAffee breaking the law.  I need a laugh.